# Write a SQL query to find the products which does not have sales at all? ( Which one is efficient and why )

Tags: sql

As per the question title I would like to understand which SQL would be efficient and why based on the below solutions assuming the data volumes are high in both the tables PRODUCTS( millions of rows ) AND SALES( billions of rows ). Here are the schema details as below. I am not interested in getting the solution for the question but I would like to get better learning on the optimal solution.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
       PRODUCT_ID     INTEGER,
       PRODUCT_NAME   VARCHAR2(30)
);
CREATE TABLE SALES
(
       SALE_ID        INTEGER,
       PRODUCT_ID     INTEGER,
       YEAR           INTEGER,
       Quantity       INTEGER,
       PRICE          INTEGER
);       

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ( 100, 'Nokia');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ( 200, 'IPhone');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ( 300, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ( 400, 'LG');

INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 1, 100, 2010, 25, 5000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 2, 100, 2011, 16, 5000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 3, 100, 2012, 8,  5000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 4, 200, 2010, 10, 9000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 5, 200, 2011, 15, 9000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 6, 200, 2012, 20, 9000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 7, 300, 2010, 20, 7000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 8, 300, 2011, 18, 7000);
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ( 9, 300, 2012, 20, 7000);
COMMIT;
```

--Solution 1

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM   PRODUCTS P
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       SALES S
ON     (P.PRODUCT_ID = S.PRODUCT_ID);
WHERE  S.QUANTITY IS NULL
```

--Solution 2

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM   PRODUCTS P
WHERE  P.PRODUCT_ID NOT IN 
       (SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID FROM SALES);
```

--Solution 3

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM   PRODUCTS P
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM SALES S WHERE S.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID);
```

Comment: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for hte database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Your three queries are *different* semantically, as written with the provided table definitions.

The first query is different from the other two, *logically*.  Unless `quantity` is declared as `NOT NULL`, then it can return matching records where the quantity is `NULL`.

The second query uses a redundant `select distinct`.  I am guessing that all decent databases would optimize it away.  The normal syntax is:

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM   PRODUCTS P
WHERE  P.PRODUCT_ID NOT IN (SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM SALES);
```

And, this is not equivalent to the third.  If `SALES.PRODUCT_ID` is ever `NULL`, then this query will return no rows at all.

Semantically, I prefer the third version with `NOT EXISTS`.  However, depending on the database one of the first two (fixed?) versions might be an iota faster.  As with any performance question, the answer depends on your data, data structure, database engine, and even potentially your hardware.